# Talend tloop long type

Tags: java, sql-server, talend, edi

I was wondering in Talend how to Loop with long ? I retrieved a list of ids (long typed) but the tLoop item only works with Integer.Is there a way to solve the problem by using an another item or way to do it ?

Regards

Comment: you can try to use tJavaFlex and pull the iterate link out of it

Comment: you can try to typecast the long values to integer and then use in tLoop (unless you always have long which is greater than integer limits)..